# css file not working on the wordpress child theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

hello i have a problem with css in my child theme its not working  this is the code i use in functions.php 
the problem is the style in file app.css is not applying in the page but when i move the same css to the costomize ( additionnal css) its working perfectely.

```
if (!function_exists('succulents_qodef_child_theme_enqueue_scripts')){

    function succulents_qodef_child_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
        
        $parent_style = 'succulents-qodef-default-style';

         wp_enqueue_style( 'customstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/app.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('succulents-qodef-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));
            // wp_enqueue_style('succulents-custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/app.css', array($parent_style));

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'succulents_qodef_child_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
}
```

when i see the code source of the page i can see the app.css but for some reason its not applying

Comment: if you are able to see the app.css in the source code than above code is fine. Please share a link inside jsfiddle / codepen to check what is the issue.

Comment: @TajKhan i have try to add !important to all my selectors and its working fine now , thank you